# What does "neither is Eid compulsory on her" imply?

Tags: eid, fard

I've seen this <strike>hadith</strike> e.g. at [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/43572):

> A woman should not raise her hands till her shoulders.  ... [snip] ... Jumu’ah is not obligatory for her, but if she attends it, she will be absolved of responsibility. **Neither is Eid compulsory on her** nor the takbir of tashriq. It is not mustahab for her to perform Fajr when it brightens up. In the loud salahs she will not raise her voice.  (Allaamah Muhammad Amin Ibn Abidin as-Shami rahimahullah)

**Question**: What does "neither is Eid compulsory on her" imply in the above <strike>hadith</strike>?

Firstly, there are two Eids: [Eid al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr), at the end of Ramadan, and [Eid al-Adha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Adha), the sacrifice feast.  But, in addition to this, I haven't before seen anyone claim that feasting or attending mosque on either Eid and and sacrificing for Eid al-Adha was not obligatory.  Perhaps there's more nuance to this that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions.

The paragraph you mentioned is not hadith. It is actually from the book *Radd al Mukhtar* in Arabic, which is used as a reference for Fatwa in Hanafi jurisprudence. You can see here written (in which would be a translated form) that Jumuah is not compulsory, so what does that mean?

> Jumu’ah is not obligatory for her, but if she attends it, she will be
>   absolved of responsibility. Neither is Eid compulsory on her

This indicates that Jumuah prayer and Eid Prayer is not wajib on women; they are mustahab for them.

Allah swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones You are welcome.